# Get Current Location Zip Code ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

How do I use the location services to get the current zip code the user is in?

Answer (score 3):

```
    //finding address given the coordinates
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]

            print(pm.postalCode) //prints zip code
        }
        else {
           print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
```

Comment: not working for Ireland http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300811/what-can-i-do-where-postalcode-inforamtion-not-available

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reverseGeocodeLocation(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:) method of the CLGeocoder class.

Comment: This should've been a comment, not an answer.